# How to check if two numbers in a list are the same

Tags: python

I was curious on how I would check if 2 numbers inside of a list are identical. For instance,

```
myList=[1,7,9,3,1,2,8]
```

**In this case, "1" is repeated in 'myList'.**

How would I make a program that checks to see if two numbers inside of a list are the same(repeated). Try to use loops so I can understand because I haven't yet learned complex functions.

Comment: -1 for complete lack of research effort and not including what you've tried.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to use loops, you'll have to use a list or a set of numbers which you've already seen. Then while looping you'll check, with the `in` operator if the number is already seen.

```
seen = []
for number in myList:
    if number in seen:
        print "Number repeated!"
    else:
        seen.append(number)
```

`set` does not allow duplicates in it, thus it's a good fit for this sort of an algorithm. As mentioned in the comments, the time complexity for checking if an element is in a set is constant for the average case (O(1)), so this is more efficient if you have a lot of numbers.

```
seen = set()
for number in myList:
    if number in seen:
        print "Number repeated!"
    seen.add(number) # won't duplicate
```

I'd say that the most pythonic way is to use `collections.Counter`, but the other answers cover this already. To use a built-in, you could generate a set of the numbers which appear more than once using a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) and `set`.

```
In [39]: seen = set()

In [40]: print list(set(x for x in myList if x in seen or seen.add(x)))
[1]
```

Here the expression will loop over all values in `myList` and add them to a `set` called `seen` if they have already been seen. Eventually, it will convert the resulting set into a list and print the contents.

Comment: In an ideal world you would make `seen` a set instead of a list, but the idea remains the same.

Comment: I think the main advantage of using a set isn't that it doesn't allow duplicates, but that membership testing -- `if number in seen:` is very fast.  If `seen` is a list, then in order to be sure that a value isn't there, it has to scan through the entire list (O(n)).  Testing whether a value is in a set is ~O(1).

Comment: Hmm very interesting to see so many ways to complete one objective

Answer (score 12):

Using [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

myList = [1, 7, 9, 3, 1, 2, 8]
counter = Counter(myList)
print(counter) # prints 'Counter({1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1})'
```

With `Collections.Counter`, you know how many times is repeated every element of your source list `myList`.

After that you can use a simple [`list comprehension`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to know which elements are repeated:

```
result = [i for i, j in counter.items() if j > 1]
print(result) # prints '[1]'
```

Comment: @ Ashwini Chaudhary: He said something like "try to use loops cause I didn't learn complex function". And I don't think using `collections.Counter` is something complex :)

Comment: +1 Great use of hyperlinking to learn advanced Python concepts.

Comment: One downside of using `Counter` is that if all you care about is whether or not a duplicate exists, then if you have a list `[0] + range(10**8)`, `Counter` will have to scan through the whole list and make 10**8 keys, even though you really only needed to read 2 elements to know the answer was yes.  Without knowing how to do the `for` loop version, simply being handed the magic of `Counter` doesn't help you adapt.

Comment: @DSM: In term of performance, I agree with you it might not be the best way to do that. But I think it's the most pythonic way. And IMHO,  knowing how to use the different python modules is a huge part of Python programming. Also it's important not to implement what's already implemented.

Comment: @segfolt: it's also important to know *how* to implement what's already implemented, and I think someone asking for us to use `for` loops is probably at that stage.

Comment: @DSM: That's right: for that there is the other answers. I think the important is that the OP can see all the ways it can be done, and nobody talked about `Collections.Counter`. Also the OP said: "try to use loops so I can understand", not "please use `for` loops". You can understand this sentence like "please don't use nested list comprehensions or too much complicated things" (because of the "so I can understand").

Answer (score 6):

You can convert your list to a Set using the built-in `set()` function, Sets cannot have duplicates. Therefore if the size of the Set and List are different, your List has duplicates.

```
if len(myList) != len(set(myList)):
    print "duplicates"
```

This assumes you don't care about what the duplicate is, you only want to know if 1 or more duplicates exist.

Answer (score 1):

You could transform the list into a set

```
myset = set(mylist)
```

and check if the length is different. If so, then there was a repetition.

This is because a set conains every element only once if several elements are equal - just like sets in the mathematical sense.

This is the easiest way if you don't need to know *which* number is duplicated.

Comment: +1, but you might want to explain how that works (transformation to set uniquifies), since the user appears to be new to Python.

Answer (score 1):

```
myList=[1,7,9,3,1,2,8]
counts = {elem:myList.count(elem) for elem in set(myList)}
for i in counts:
    if counts[i] > 1:
       print '{} occurs more than once'.format(i)
```

If you don't want to use a dictionary comprehension:

```
myList=[1,7,9,3,1,2,8]
counts = {}
for elem in set(myList):
    counts[elem] = myList.count(elem)
    if counts[elem] > 1:
        print '{} occurs more than once'.format(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe not the easiest to understand, but this is how I do it.

```
seen = set()
duplicated = [t for t in my_list if t in seen or seen.add(t)]
```

it is equivalent to (and easier to follow)

```
duplicated = []
seen = set()
for elem in my_list:
    if elem in seen:
        duplicated.append(elem)
    else:
        seen.add(elem)
```