# Is there a better way to compare multiple functions?

Tags: python-3.x, function, if-statement

Is there a better way of comparing functions within another function? How can I handle too many conditions without having ugly code?

```
#Function to Convert string to integer
def input(X):
    if type (X) == str:
        X = int(X)
    return X

#Function to check input equality 
def equality(A,B,C):
    if input(A) == input(B) or input(B) == input(C) or input(C) == input(A):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if two numbers in a list are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155993/how-to-check-if-two-numbers-in-a-list-are-the-same)

Answer (score 0):

This will help you..

```
def input(X):
    if type(X) == str or type(X) == int:
        return int(X)

def equality(*argv):
    tmp_list = []
    for arg in argv:
        tmp_list.append(input(arg))

    return not len(tmp_list) == len(set(tmp_list))
```

I changed the function to work with *args and now you can check more than three at once.

```
>>> equality(10,11,20,20)
True
>>> equality(10,'11',20,'20')
True
>>> equality('10','20',30,'40')
False
```

Comment: Interesting approach, do you know if append will be efficient when input grows too much?