# How to find two same number in a list?

Tags: python

This is so simple, yet why so complicated ?

I was to return true if there are two same integer in a list and false otherwise, but I can't seem to get it right.
Why?

Here's what i did:

python

```
def high(n): 

    for x in n:
        if x==x:
            return True
        elif x!=x:
            return False
```

Thanks,

Comment: Under what conditions do you expect `x==x` to be `False`?  Or `x!=x` to be `True`?  Also note that your loop isn't really a loop, since it will never visit anything past the first element of the list.  This doesn't seem like a serious effort.

Comment: if a number in the list is  the same (x==x), then true, but if a number on the list is not the same, x!=x, then false. How did you not figure it out ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155993/how-to-check-if-two-numbers-in-a-list-are-the-same.

Comment: @AdamCora I did figure it out.  You simply have no understanding of Python.  Answer:  `x==x` is true and `x!=x` is false for any integer.  How can that possibly not be obvious?  I challenge you to give an example of an integer that is not equal to itself.  You can't.

Comment: Could try *collections.Counter*

Comment: @AdamCora "a number in the list is the same"? Same as what?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try checking what happens when you run the code? Say, you have a list of `[1, 2, 2]`.

1. For loop takes the first element "1" and assigns it to `x`
2. `if x == x` same as `if 1 == 1` will always be `True` for every element.
3. Function returns `True` even though the number 1 doesn't appear twice.

You shouldn't be comparing values to themselves, it will always return True. Instead, take each value and check if it exists in the list past the moment you first see it.

Once you've gone through the entire list and haven't seen a match with any numbers, return False.

```
def high(n: list[int]):
    for index, x in enumerate(n):
        if x in n[index+1:]:
            return True
    return False
```

Or you can be fancy and write a one-liner:

```
def high(n: list):
    return any(x in n[index+1:] for index, x in enumerate(n))
```

**EDIT:**
As suggested in the comments, a more efficient solution would be to use the `collections.Counter`

```
from collections import Counter

def high(n):
    if any(i > 1 for i in Counter(n).values()):
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: This costs *O(n ^ 2)* in time complexity when this problem can be solved in linear time complexity.

Comment: @blhsing, the OP was looking to understand the algorithm. Using something like `collections.Counter` would give linear complexity but it won't help their understanding.

Comment: If anything, using `Counter` helps make the algorithm more easily understandable without letting the implementation details get in the way. And one can easily implement `Counter` with a dict without using the library anyway. The point is to point the OP to a good solution, which this answer is not.

Comment: @blhsing, I still think that showing the simple algorithm in pure Python has more value if a person is trying to understand how this works but I've added a solution using Counter.

Comment: It makes no sense to use `Counter` for this.  The obvious solution is just `return len(set(n)) != len(n)`.  It's the simplest possible solution and it runs in O(n) time.  It's a standard idiom that people use all the time.  Nothing else makes sense.

Comment: @TomKarzes For some reason when I saw pavel's comment about `Counter` I in my mind turned this question into a "return all duplicate values in a list" problem rather than a "return True if there is any duplicate" problem, and started commenting based on this impression of a question. `return len(set(n)) != len(n)` is short and simple but is not necessarily a good solution because it does not allow any short circuiting. Returning `True` immediately, e.g. `seen=set(); for i in n: if i in seen: return True; seen.add(i); return False` (indentation adjusted) would be more efficient on average.

Comment: @blhsing That is a good point, but it depends on the "expected" case.  When I use this, it's usually to confirm that there are no duplicates, in which case what I showed will be fastest.  But if duplicates are likely, then an explicit iteration could be faster, depending on the expected number of elements you need to examine before encountering a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

````
list=[1,2,3,2,3,4,6,4,5,7,9,5]
store=[]
for i in list:
    if i not in store:
        print('true')
    else:
        print('false')
```'
````

Comment: This costs *O(n ^ 2)* in time complexity when this problem can be solved in linear time complexity.

Answer (score -2):

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3]
    
seen = set()
dupl = [i for i in list if i in  seen or seen.add(i)]
print(dupl)
```

Comment: This will incorrectly output a value twice or more if the value occurs more than twice in the input. Also, it is never Pythonic to use a function for its side effect in a list comprehension.